# System.DirectoryServices produces .PageRequestManagerServerErrorException when deployed in production

Tags: directoryservices

I am getting this error

Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

when I am running my application in the IIS.

I think it is with the System.Directory.Services which produces the eror. This does not produce one on my local machine.

Below is a snippet of my code.

```
string[] a = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ADEntry = new    
     System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + a[0] + "/" + a[1]);
string Arranger = ADEntry.Properties["FullName"].Value.ToString();
```

Error produced:

Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500
Line: 940
Char: 13
Code: 0
`URI: http://hrmd/ScriptResource.axd? d=qoTxFIEhQnPsyvjBHKKk60V8KyVGjuJO4u_QPoCxnkdWP8h53oPF6xWRYBSVhraJ1rWB7MwHQ0UUukOxxZP-__EfNy8U9HNSn9H4TG_rigG5a2MrWox2WPR4280GIrb57NZ6Ajhx2gKgc0sQKMnAVw2&t=48e38e19`

Thanks in advance.